# Why rails select generates extra div block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I am using rails 3.2.13 and bootstrap 2.3.1.0, have the following form

```
<%= form_for(Website.new, :url => websites_path, :validate => true) do |f| %>
        <div><br />
          <%= f.text_field :site_name, :autofocus => true, placeholder: "Name"  %> </div> <br />
          <%= f.select :url_scheme, options_for_select(["http://", "https://"], selected: "http://"),{} %>
          <%= f.text_field :site_address, placeholder: "Address" %>
          <div><%= f.submit "Add" %></div>
<% end %>
```

So the f.select field generates extra div block as follows, is it normal?

```
<select id="website_url_scheme" name="website[url_scheme]" class="selecter-element" data-validate="true"><option value="http://" selected="selected">http://</option>
<option value="https://">https://</option></select>

<div class="selecter  closed"><span class="selecter-selected">http://</span><div class="selecter-options"><span class="selecter-item selected" data-value="http://">http://</span><span class="selecter-item" data-value="https://">https://</span></div></div>
```

Comment: if you didnt do anything special, then its normal

Comment: I didn't do anything special

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, its normal.

That DIV is the one that's made visible when you actually click on the Dropdown. Remember, this is a custom DropDown. When you click on it, a DIV with all the option-values is constructed and displayed. When an option is selcted, class CLOSED is added to the div.